# Discard Chars After Space In C# String

Tags: c#, .net, string

I would like to discard the remaining characters (which can be any characters) in my string after I encounter a space.
Eg. I would like the string "10 1/2" to become "10";
Currently I'm using Split, but this seems like overkill:

```
string TrimMe = "10 1/2";
string[] cleaned = TrimMe.Split(new char[] {' '});
return cleaned[0];
```

I feel there should be an easier way.

Comment: Your way is simple and fine for this. Technically it's inefficient, but in a "who-the-hell-cares" kind of way.

Comment: I think you meant "return cleaned[0]" instead of "return string[0]".  Agreed that it is the simplest and most readable solution.

Comment: @redoc - right, I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some other options:

```
string result = Regex.Match(TrimMe, "^[^ ]+").Value;
// or
string result = new string(TrimMe.TakeWhile(c => c != ' ').ToArray());
```

However, IMO what you started with is much simpler and easier to read.

EDIT: Both solutions will handle empty strings, return the original if no spaces were found, and return an empty string if it starts with a space.

Comment: Your linq answer is clever, but I think you're right, I'll stick with my split solution. Thank you.

Comment: I agree... the LINQ answer is quite clever. I'd hate to see it in production code. :)

Comment: Same here.  I'd hate to see it in production code.  Also, I've run into situations where there are more than one space in the string where we would need to access a certain index of the string array.  Clever answer but IMHO not the most efficient or readable.

Answer (score 11):

This should work:

```
Int32 indexOfSpace = TrimMe.IndexOf(' ');
if (indexOfSpace == 0)
    return String.Empty; // space was first character
else if (indexOfSpace > 0)
    return TrimMe.Substring(0, indexOfSpace);
else
    return TrimMe; // no space found
```

Comment: Not entirely sure it was needed though, looks like Substring handles length=0 anyway. I'll leave it though.

Answer (score 11):

I like this for readability:

```
trimMe.Split(' ').First();
```

Comment: Split (' ') does not have First () functionality.

Comment: @Wanna Use `using System.Linq;`

Comment: This is very helpful when automating sending an email, when you cell contains First and last name separated with space. Love it ! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Similar to another answer, but terser:

```
int indexSpace = trimMe.IndexOf(" ");
return trimMe.Substring(0, indexSpace >= 0 ? indexSpace : trimMe.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split is probably your most elegant/easiest solution. Other options include regular expressions and/or parsing/lexical analysis. Both will be more complex than the example you've provided calls for.